# Regression with weirdly structured data

Tags: r

I have a data frame with Tweets from 500 different users. Each user has 1-200 tweets. For every tweet I have recorded the number of followers the user has, as well as the engagement for the tweet (retweets + favorites). I am now trying to run an lm regression with engagement as by DV and followers as my IV.

The issue is that the IV (followers) is kinda both categorical and continuous. For users with 200 tweets in the data set, there will be 200 tweets with the same number of followers attached to them. Basically, the IV is categorical with 500 different categories within a span of 8000 and 1.9 million. The consequence is that the data points in my plot are 'stacked' on top of each other and the regline suffers. Is there a way I can restructure/transform my data so that I can do a better linear representation visually? (the linear relationship is itself confirmed by running summary of the lm).

Hope someone understands this rather weird issue and can give me a helping hand!

Comment: It sounds like you need to aggregate the engagement measure. Perhaps mean or median engagement by user?

Comment: So a mean score of engagement for each user and then do a regression on the 500 mean vs. the 500 different numbers of followers?

Comment: I think so. That way you get a 1:1 relation of engagement with followers. It also makes sense when you think about what you want to express in the model: the hypothesis (presumably) is that more followers = _on average_ more engagement.